# What replaced HttpOperationHandler in WCF Web API to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

In upgrading an old project that was built using WCF Web API to now use ASP.NET Web API, I have run into a few classes that implement `HttpOperationHandler<HttpRequestMessage, T>`. I'm unable to find an equivalent class in the new assemblies. Does something similar exist or will I need a different approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept of Operation handlers has been replaced with Filters and model binders.

Here are some links that you might find useful:

- [How to Migrate from WCF Web API to ASP.NET Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Migrate%20from%20WCF%20Web%20API%20to%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API)
- Mike's blog on [How WebAPI does Parameter Binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx)
- [Getting started tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api) on ASP.NET WebAPI page.

Hope this helps.